# What this be considered bad security practice/violation?

Tags: security, design-patterns, service, architecture, microservices

1. Service A has a key to talk to Service B
2. Service B has an HTTPS API endpoint for starting a job and the consumer of the endpoint supplies through the API the connection string of the message queue of where to send the job metadata when it's completed.

This way A is fully decoupled from B. But is it safe?

Comment: Please elaborate on your definition of `safe`.

Answer (score 1):

> This way A is fully decoupled from B.

In order to fully decouple A and B, you can add additional service to verify the validity of the key that you used to access service B. So both Services can consult above introduced auth service to manage and verify the lifecycle of keys that used for access purposes. The implementation varies depending on the authentication/authorization implementation(JWT, OAuth etc) used.

> But is it safe?

Security can not guaranteed only by decoupling service but you have to consider many aspect with it(Transport, database, server hardware, network etc.) Can you provide more specific details of this?